# Re-bin a data frame in R

Tags: r, binning

I have a data frame which holds activity (A) data across time (T) for a number of subjects (S) in different groups (G). The activity data were sampled every 10 minutes. What I would like to do is to re-bin the data into, say, 30-minute bins (either adding or averaging values) keeping the subject Id and group information.

Example. I have something like this:

```
S   G   T   A
1   A   30  25
1   A   40  20
1   A   50  15
1   A   60  20
1   A   70  5
1   A   80  20
2   B   30  10
2   B   40  10
2   B   50  10
2   B   60  20
2   B   70  20
2   B   80  20
```

And I'd like something like this:

```
S   G   T   A
1   A   40  20
1   A   70  15
2   B   40  10
2   B   70  20
```

Whether time is the average time (as in the example) or the first/last time point and whether the activity is averaged (again, as in the example) or summed is not important for now.

I will appreciate any help you can provide on this. I was thinking about creating a script in Python to re-bin this particular dataframe, but I thought that there may be a way of doing it in R in a way that may be applied to any dataframe with differing numbers of columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to come to the wished dataframe.
I have reproduced your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(S = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6)),
                 G = c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
                 T = rep(seq(30,80,10),2),
                 A = c(25, 20, 15, 20, 5, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20))
```

The classical way could be:

```
df[df$T == 40 | df$T == 70,]
```

The more modern *tidyverse* way is

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(T == 40 | T ==70)
```

If you want to get the average of each group of G filtered for T==40 and 70:

```
df %>% filter(T == 40 | T == 70) %>% 
       group_by(G) %>% 
       mutate(A = mean(A))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. If I understand well, these methods would allow me to reduce the size of the dataframe keeping the rows manually selected through values for T, discarding the rest of the data. I wonder whether there is a way to summarize all rows in the dataframe to a given lower number rows. In my example, I averaged three 10-min bins into 30-min binned rows.

Comment: OK, then I do not understand your wanted output. In your example you only averaged over G == B, I do not understand what you did for G == A. Do you mean this:
    df %>% group_by(G, A) %>% summarise(mean = mean(T)) %>% 
    rename(T=mean)

Comment: Now that I think of it, G (group) doesn't really matter here, I put it there because it is part of my data. What I wanted to do is, for each subject, average or sum values of A every given number of minutes in T. In the example, I started with a sample every ten minutes and then I averaged the activity (and the time, although for time it's pretty much the same if it returns an average, start time, or end time as long as it the intervals are the same between time points) every 30 minutes. So I started with 6 values per subject and ended with 2, spaced by 30 minutes. Thanks a lot for your help!